# Fragment - Error inflating

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, fragment

I am having some problems with my code. I keep getting these errors. I tried searching google and looked at several possible solutions but none of them worked. I have sat with this problem all day and can't really progress with my app until it is solved. I appreciate any help.

```
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingmenu/com.example.slidingmenu.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> inflating class fragment
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> inflating class fragment
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:16)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4765)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:16)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   ... 11 more
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate
> id 0x7f0a0006, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a0001 with another fragment
> for null
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4751)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   ... 29 more
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.slidingmenu;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import model.NavDrawerItem;

import adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, "22"));

        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        SlideMenuClickListener s = new SlideMenuClickListener();
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            s.displayView(0);
        }
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            displayView(position);
        }

        private void displayView(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;

            case 1:
                break;

            case 2: 
                break;
            }

            if(fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating the fragment");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="sadsa" />
</fragment>
```

EDIT:

ADDED HomeFragment.java

```
package com.example.slidingmenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedIntanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just before I read the code fully - have you done a Clean (Eclipse) or Invalidate and Restart (Android Studio / InteliJ) ?

Comment: I have done a clean several times. I haven't tried to restart Eclispe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section looks important:

```
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:16)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4765)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>     02-22 19:11:14.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2075):   at com.example.slidingmenu.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:16)
```

Notice the first and last lines of the bit I've posted are the same? The tells me the fragment is trying to inflate itself into itself. Where's the fragment layout/code?

**Edit**

The problem is in your fragment xml. The rood view you use is 'fragment', the fragment tag in xml meaning 'replace this with an instance of the fragment I declare in my id/name'!

The effect being, each time your fragment is inflated, it tries to inflate itself inside itself...

What you need to do is replace the root tag in your fragment xml with either `merge` (if you know what this does) or a `ViewGroup` such as `FrameLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`

Comment: I have spotted my own mistake I think. Aaaaah I am so stupid. You are right about what you wrote.

Answer (score -1):

Try extending your MainActivity from Fragment Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Comment: This wasn't a reasonable answer because you only had to read the logcat to see this was not the issue, as android is good at printing such advice